# How to prevent the reload of a webView in a fragment when another fragment in the top was closed

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I'm making an app with webviews.
I just have a single activity containing 
a FrameLayout to dynamically add fragments.

Every fragment contains a webView.

Everything works fine, but when I remove a fragment
from the stack, the webview of the fragment in the
top of the stack is reloaded so the content inside the
script of the html is called again.

The restoreState() method is not working.

This is the onCreateView of the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wv_container, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webviewcontainer);
    if(webViewBundle == null)
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/main.html");
    else
        webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    return view;
}
```

This is the onPause() method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    webViewContent.saveState(webViewBundle);
}
```

How should I prevent the page reloading for my case?
I don't want to hack the html with flags or something like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `saveState` method in your `onPause` returns a [`WebBackForwardList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebBackForwardList.html), which contains a list of [`WebHistory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html) items. These are basically the titles, urls and favicons from recently visited pages. It does not cache the contents of the downloaded url.

Try looking at the method [saveWebArchive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveWebArchive%28java.lang.String%29) instead.